# R: Return a vector using %in% operator

Tags: r, list, vector, set

I have a vector with delimiters and I want to generate a vector of the same length with boolean values based on whether or not one of the delimited values contains what I am after. I cannot find a way to do this neatly in vector-based logic. As an example:

```
x <- c('a', 'a; b', 'ab; c', 'b; c', 'c; a', 'c')
```

Using some magic asking whether 'a' %in% x, I want to get the vector:

```
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE
```

I initially tried the following:

```
'a' %in% trimws(strsplit(x, ';'))
```

But this unexpectedly collapses the entire list and returns TRUE, rather than a vector, since one of the elements in x is 'a'. Is there a way to get the vector I am looking for without rewriting the code into a for-loop?

Answer (score 3):

**Update: To consider white spaces:**

```
library(stringr)
x <- str_replace_all(string=x, pattern=" ", repl="")
x
[1] "a"    "a;b"  "ab;c" "b;c"  "c;a"  "c" 

str_detect(x, 'a$|a;')
```

```
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

**First answer:**
If you want to use `str_detect` we have to account on `a` + delimiter `;`:

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(x, 'a$|a;')
```

```
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: There is an issue here which is whitespace (I cannot guarantee the data will not have meaningless whitespace). This is why I had the surrounding trimws(strsplit(x, ';')). Is there a way to handle this or must I use \\b in the str_detect?

Answer (score 2):

Base R:

```
grepl("a", x)
```

or (when you want to use explicitly %in%):

```
sapply(strsplit(x,""), function(x){ "a" %in% x})
```

When working with strings and letters I always use the great library `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
x <- c('a', 'a; b', 'ab; c', 'b; c', 'c; a', 'c')
str_detect(x, "a")
```

Comment: Actually there is a problem with both solutions, which is substrings. Both your suggestions return:
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE

When I want:
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE

I don't want to detect substrings but only an exact match.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to use `%in%`, here is a base R option

```
> mapply(`%in%`, list("a"), strsplit(x, ";\\s+"))
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

A more efficient way might be using `grepl` like below

```
> grepl("\\ba\\b",x)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read each item separately with `scan`, trim leading and trailing WS as you attempted, and test each resulting character vector in turn with:

```
 sapply(x, function(x){"a" %in% trimws( scan( text=x, what="",sep=";", quiet=TRUE))})
    a  a; b ab; c  b; c  c; a     c 
 TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

The top row of the result is just the names and would not affect a logical test that depended on this result. There is an `unname` function if needed.